# I want to create two linked list from one insert method, how to send head reference to the method multiple times? I am getting input error at run-time

Tags: c, data-structures

main and insertion methods

```
int main()
{
    struct node *head=NULL,*head_1=NULL;
    int n,i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the data \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        insert(&head,n);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {  
        printf("Enter the data \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        insert(&head_1,n);
    }
    display(head);
    return 0;
}

 void insert(struct node **head,int a)
{
    struct node* temp,*new;
    new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data=a;
    new->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        (*head) = new;
        temp=new;
    }
    temp->next=new;
    temp=new;
}
```

program stops as soon as i put in the first data for the first linked list, I could declare the head pointers globally but then i would have to declare insert method twice.

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Comment: If the `if` clause isn't entered, `temp` isn't initialised. The condition `head == NULL` will never be true if you pass in the address of a pointer, which is the intended use.

Comment: Why are you confusing yourself with definitions like this `struct node *head` and some lines later `struct node **head`. Calling different things differently helps.

Comment: @MOehm thank you very much

Comment: Also In C There Is No Need To Cast The Result Of `malloc()`.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @alk Also When Answering On SO All Those Caps Aren't Needed
@AmarBal Casting your `malloc`s is a good practice, keep doing it. If you ever happen to make a mistake somewhere for example declaring `int *` instead of `int **` your compiler will warn you, small errors are then easily spotted.

Comment: @ft_error: I object it being good practise. Using a cast just introduces one more possibility to introduce any typos. There are other safe ways to always pass to `malloc()` the right type. Like `int * p = malloc(42 * sizeof *p);` allocates 42 `int`s and would even survive (*without further adjustment*) if you'd just changed `int` to `long`.

Comment: @alk I understand your point but if a typo had to be in the cast the compiler would then spot it, the chances are low you did the same on the variable declaration. The `malloc(42 * sizeof *p)` method is a good method to always get the right size but it wouldn't spot a typo in the declaration such as `int *` instead of `int **` while the cast would.

Comment: @ft_error: Well, I'd say if you mix `*` and `**` you'll notice that something is going very, very wrong quite soon elsewise ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here i corrected your code

```
int main()
{
    struct node *head=NULL,*head_1=NULL;
    int n,i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the data \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (insert(&head,n))    /* Check for malloc failure */
            /* Error */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {  
        printf("Enter the data \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (insert(&head_1,n))
            /* Error */
    }
    display(head);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * The insert() function adds a new element at the head of the list.
 */

int insert(struct node **head, int a)
{
    struct node *new;      /* temp is not needed */
    new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!new)              /* Check for malloc fail */
        return 1;          /* Non-zero return value (error) */
    new->data=a;
    new->next = *head;     /* Save the head in new (don't care if it's NULL) */
    *head = new;           /* Update head */
    return 0;              /* All went fine */
}

/*
 * The append() function adds a new element at the end of the list.
 */

int append(struct node **head, int a)
{
    struct node *new;
    new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!new)              /* Same as before */
        return 1;
    new->data = a;
    new->next = NULL;
    if (*head == NULL)     /* List doesn't exist yet */
    {
        *head = new;       /* Initialize the list */
        return 0;
    }                      /* List exists, find the end */
    struct node *actual;   /* This is what we iterate with */
    actual = *head;
    while (actual->next != NULL)
        actual = actual->next;   /* Go through the list */      
    actual->next = new;     /* Append new */
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to always check `malloc`'s return. I chose to return 0 as the "all fine" code in `insert` function but you can invert that if you want. I hope you understand everything, if not, ask in comment and i will add extra explanations.

As you saw with these two examples the element creation part is the same for both functions, this is why you should make some `struct node *newnode(int data)` function to make your code lighter.

Comment: You may want to notice that `then` and `else` branches do exactly the same thing.

Comment: You are right, that's fixed. It maybe is a bit less understandable now.

Comment: I used the temp pointer so that i can print the list in FIFO(forward order), using head to store the starting address and temp to traverse, the code you gave prints the list in a reverse order because you keep updating the head to the last address. And thank you for pointing out the practice of checking for malloc's return.

Comment: @AmarBal I added an append function so you can print your list in the right order.